# How to compress the file size of visual svn server repository

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, svnadmin

I need to compress the file size of VisualSVN Server repository. I tried using following code

```
        SVNPATH svnadmin pack REPOSITORYPATH
```

But this command is reducing any filesize reduction. Is there any way to clean unused revisions using VisualSVN Server?

Comment: Not reducing any file size

Answer (score 0):

Packing a Subversion repository will only provide minimal space savings; all it's doing is combining sharded revisions into a single file.

**If** there is space to be reclaimed, it will be because you have revisions which can be made smaller via rep sharing or better diffing/compression that was introduced in newer versions of Subversion. This assumes that you have a long history that you created with an older version of the server and have upgraded over time; older versions will be "bigger" than newer ones.

The only way to retroactively take advantage of those improvements is to "rebuild" the repository completely with the current version. You can do this in one of two ways:

1. Perform an svnadmin dump/load cycle, as described [in the manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate.svnadmin). You'll be "migrating" the repository from and to the same server, but the principle is the same.
2. Create a new repository, use [`svnsync`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.replication) to push everything into it, then remove the old one and attach the new one in the location where you're currently serving the repository. You'll have some extra work to do with permissions & hook scripts.

Of course, you need to be sure that you have solid backups before attempting either method.